# Immense noise from fan and disk and 1962 error on a Lenovo ThinkCentre desktop

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, fan

I was getting a 1962 error from few days on my ThinkCentre desktop. I ran a 14-hour disk check. There was not a single bad sector found. But some how I can boot in many attempts.

I also installed to check if other things may be causing the issue. I tried Fan test:

[image]

[image]

Despite no bad sector found still can disk be faulty?

Update these are the errors I see:

[image]

[image]

[image]

According to the Lenovo website, diagnostic test Hard disk doesn't have any issue: I conducted this test on Jan 4, 2019.

> Can their diagnostic miss something or issue is with SATA cable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In this Lenovo thread, the error was the SATA cable (https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-All-In-One-AIO-Desktops/ERROR-CODE-1962-NO-OPERATING-SYSTEM-FOUND/td-p/1034873)   Also look at this thread about the error  (https://windowsreport.com/fix-pc-error-1962/)  . See if either of these threads help

Comment: It’s not clear what your issue is? Is the system not booting all the time? Does it lock up at all while you’re using it? What errors are you receiving - exactly? What is the actual model of your PC? This post has a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: This video suggests clearing the cmos to fix that error code>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MrqBgAcWNs

Comment: Question updated with the actual error I see.

Comment: Unable to understand what this guy is doing here → https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MrqBgAcWNs